# FIll a option list with an array PHP

Tags: php

I want to fill an option list with an array.
THis is what I already got:

```
$array = array("Amy" , "Steve", "Tim", "Ron");

foreach ($array as $option) {


// Do something (what I dont know how to do:-))
}
```

Comment: So all you need is to learn HTML

Comment: I want to do it dynamiccaly. The answer of Bas works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hi, Add this code:**

```
echo "<select>";
foreach ($array as $option)
    echo "<option value='" . $option ."'>" . $option . "</option>";
echo "</select>";
```

*Hope this helps!*

Comment: And edit your question  please your qoutes are incorrect :' to a " !

Answer (score 1):

You need to read about [HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html/) :

```
<select>
    <?php foreach ($array as $key => value) : ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $key ?>">
            <?php echo $value ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```